# Windows phone 8 consuming a WCF service operation contract error

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8

I have a WCF service hosted by in a website I developed. The site is hosted by a hosting company. I also have a windows phone 8 application that consumes the service. My problem is everytime I query an operation contract with a parameter I get an error "System.ServiceModel.COmmunicationException: The remote server returned error: NotFound" but if I query an operation that takes no parameter the service works.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IParcelService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string TrackParcel(string pNumber);
}

public class ParcelService:IParcelService
{
    public string TrackParcel(string pNumber)
    {
        return "some string";
    }
}
```

The above a snippet from the service then on the client i have a reference to the service and I call it a follows

```
var service = new ParcelClient();
service.TrackParcel("1234");
service.TrackParcelCompleted +=(s,args) =>{var res = args.Result;//At this point reslt throws an exception};
```

Comment: Any Chance of some code to look at so I can replicate to try and debug this?

Comment: I added a code example.

Comment: What this line of code `service.TrackParcelCompleted += ...` present? What's the significance here?

Comment: @Rahul - It is a callback method to the Async service call. The service results are contained in the args parameter.